# Transpose on row with multiple (dynamic) columns to several rows (number of original columns) with two columns

Tags: t-sql, row, transpose

I have a recordset (one row only):

**Col1 Col2 ... Coln**

Val1 Val2 ... Valn

I need to transpose it:

**Field Value**

Col1 Val1

Col2 Val2

... ...

Coln Valn

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT Field = 'Col1', Value = Val1
FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT Field = 'Col2', Value = Val2
FROM TableA
UNION ALL
...
```